# .htaccess not working on localhost | lampp | Ubuntu

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, lampp

I am trying to achieve url rewrite to remove php extension from the php files, but I cannot figure out what's wrong! 
I am using lampp on ubuntu machine and I even set the AllowOverride from none to All in httpd.conf:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All   <--- I set it from "None" to "All"
```

and I have placed my .htacces file in the root of my project folder ie. projects/test/ (I don't even know this is right place the .htaccess file).My localhost url is like: `http://localhost/projects/test/abc.php`. I want it to be set as `http://localhost/projects/test/abc`.Here's my url rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I even tried with `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

Comment: `I cannot figure out what's wrong!` and what can you figure out? What happens when you use your rules? What does your error_log and rewrite_log show you? is the mod_rewrite enabled within your loadmodules on the httpd.conf of your server?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorances, I am new to .htaccess stuff. As I said, I want to remove .php extension from abc.php. The problem is the browser still shows the url as http://localhost/projects/test/abc.php (which should have been rather as http://localhost/projects/test/abc).
Sorry again, I don't know where to look for those log files you mentioned.

Comment: With the current rule you are adding the `.php` extension instead of removing it.

Comment: Please use a search engine first, as this is a trivial task using mod_rewrite and it was solved a few thousand times before.

Comment: @feeela I'm following from the tutorial mention here: http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/
and I've combined the code with different stackoverflow answers. Can you write the code for .php extension removal.

Comment: Might be a bit basic, but as there is a typo in `.htaccess` in the subject line of the question, have you checked the file name is spelled correctly?

Comment: @steveukx misspelt htaccess in the topic. The filename is ok.

Comment: @nexuscreator it was worth a shot...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, I would check that the Apache modules you need are enabled. mod_rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Using phpinfo(); the 'mod_rewrite' is mentioned in "Loaded Modules"  section in apache2configuration.

Comment: My bad, sorry, you mentioned this already. What I would do to troubleshoot is upload the site and the htaccess to hosted server by a thrid party that you yourself haven't configured and see if its an htaccess problem or an apache configuration problem